# C# Windows Universal Application consuming WebAPI gives Unauthorized response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, win-universal-app

I am trying to consume a Web API in windows universal application on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 15...

I am using following code to get the employee list from WebAPI.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59591/");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Employee/GetAllEmployee").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var employeelist = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

But in response I am getting

> Status Code: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'.

The same code works fine if I create a Windows Forms Application.

Is there anything specific I need to do in order to use Web API in Windows Universal Application?

Comment: This means you need to pass a `Authentication` header in your request to validate the client.Doesn't the server return a `WWW-Authenticate` header in response?Do you have control over the server?What is the name of your controller? `api/Employee/GetAllEmployee` might be wrong.Use your controller name instead of `api`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach the localhost from a UWP application. The security model does not allow this.

You can get some details about how isolation is working [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ835817(v=win.10).aspx):

> Network isolation and loopback
>
> IP loopback addresses and the loopback interface have traditionally
>   been used for communication between different applications over the
>   network, as well as for interprocess communication within several
>   applications on a local computer.
>
> Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot be used for
>   interprocess communication (between two different apps) because this
>   is restricted by network isolation. Network communication using an IP
>   loopback address is allowed within an app within the same process for
>   communication purposes.
>
> For more information on enabling developer access to IP loopback
>   addresses between apps for debugging purposes, see How to enable
>   loopback and debug network isolation.

For debugging purpose, you can turn it off. You can find some documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx)

> A developer can also use the CheckNetIsolation.exe tool to manually
>   add loopback exemptions for an app.
>
> To exempt an app from loopback restrictions, the app ID for the
>   package must be provided. The example command below exempts an app
>   from loopback restrictions.
>
> CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a
>   –p=S-1-15-2-4125766819-3228448775-2449327860-2490758337-1264241865-3581724871-2122349299